# APIdemo invoke search problem android

Tags: android

For invoke search android example, every time query search result is received by onCreate().
How can i make it received by onNewIntent(). What kind of operation can cause onNewIntent() receive intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity needs to declare `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest for `onNewIntent()` to be called.  If a new intent is received and an instance of the activity does not exist on the activity stack `onCreate()` will be called.  If it does exist in the activity stack, `onNewIntent()` will be called instead.

The docs for [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) go into a bit more detail.